# Windows Forms Application which doesn't start with form

Tags: c#

By default when you make a Windows c# application it starts with opening some form

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Is it possible to do some stuff in Main function before creating any form - create some objects, execute some methods of this objects and depending on the result create some form at last or in other case don't create any form at all - close application?

Comment: At least try... I mean seriously?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. You can modify `static void Main()` any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.  Did you try?

```
static void Main()
{
    // you can add code here
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    // and/or here
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // and so on...
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

So maybe something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    var someObject = SomeFactory.Fetch(someCriteria);
    if (someObject.SomeValue == false)
        Application.Exit();

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

or perhaps:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var someObject = SomeFactory.Fetch(someCriteria);
    if (someObject.SomeValue)
        Application.Run(new FormForValueBeingSet());
    else
        Application.Run(new FormForValueNotBeingSet());
}
```

Code is just code, you can modify it and add/edit/remove whatever you want to.  The fact that it's a WinForms application doesn't change the basic premise that on application launch it executes `static void Main()`.  Whatever's in the method is going to be executed.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth mentioning that's *not* a good idea to add/edit/remove whatever you want from designer generated code :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice - I agree with your motivation...but the more I think about it the sillier this question gets.  We could talk about designer code, but how can we ignore STAThread then COM and threading, well how about the message pump? See what I mean?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, you make a fair point.  If the OP is unsure about adding code here, the OP is already out of his depth and needs to sit down with a good book!

Comment: To complicate issues, WPF executes a XAML file as the entry object by default.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can.**

You can test this by placing some code before the form creation code ...

```
static void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime tomorrow = now.AddDays(1);

    if (DateTime.Compare(now, tomorrow) == 0)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

... then place a breakpoint at the beginning of Main()

... and then step through the code to see what effect it has.

Comment: ohaiyo!  I don't see enough Japanese folks on here.